# How to launch Glassfish v3 without backgrounding

Tags: glassfish, svc

Glassfish v3 is launched as follows:

```
./bin/asadmin start-domain <domain-name>
```

This script eventually runs:

```
exec "$JAVA" -jar "$AS_INSTALL_LIB/admin-cli.jar" "$@"
```

admin-cli.jar eventually launches another process, effectively putting itself into the background.

I would like to launch glassfish without putting itself in the background for the purpose of monitoring with [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) (ie: svc).  Is this possible?

The documentation talks about using inittab [here](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-4335/ablwy?a=view) which seems like it would also require a way to launch it without forking or backgrounding so some other process (eg: inittab, evc, etc.) can watch the process id and restart it if it crashes.  However, in this inittab example, is it using the same backgrounding cmd line, so I don't know how inittab can possibly respawn the process when it doesn't know what process id to watch.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use [asadmin start-domain -v](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-7701/start-domain-1?l=en&a=view)...

Note: log statements are sent to the log file AND System.out/System.err.

Comment: Thanks, that's it.  I didn't associate the verbose flag with backgrounding, but it makes sense now.  Thank you.